# Create a custom layout size?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

### Some info

I'm trying to optimize my app for a 5.1" device, actually i have a layout and a large layout ( optimized for a 7.0" ) but if i try to put as device a device with 5.1" instead of changing the size of the main layout it open and change the large layout size...

### Question?

So the question is, how can i create a layout with a custom size? I would create a layout-normall if it's possible and set it to a 5.1" because also the main layout is optimized for a 5.0"...

[image]

PS: (i'm yet using ConstraintLayout and it's not working on switching device )
pic releated :

[image]

Comment: your approach is already wrong; you should create a single activity for all devices

Comment: use `RelativeLayout`s, `ConstraintLayout`s

Comment: Updated the question, @OmarAbdelhafiz i'm yet using ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the *Screen size* resource qualifiers to supply your alternate layouts:

```
/res/layout/mylayout.xml
/res/layout-large/mylayout.xml
```

I recommend that you stop doing this, and never use screen size resource qualifiers in the future. As you've noticed, the difference between "normal" and "large" is unclear, and plenty of phones count as "large".

You're much better off using *Smallest width* resource qualifiers:

```
/res/layout/mylayout.xml
/res/layout-sw360dp/mylayout.xml
/res/layout-sw600dp/mylayout.xml
```

Providing your alternate resources in this way gives you **precise control** over when a particular layout is used. Note that you can use any number here; `sw487dp` is totally valid.

You can read more about it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

> The **smallestWidth** of a device takes into account screen decorations and system UI. For example, if the device has some persistent UI elements on the screen that account for space along the axis of the smallestWidth, the system declares the smallestWidth to be smaller than the actual screen size, because those are screen pixels not available for your UI. Thus, the value you use should be the actual smallest dimension required by your layout (usually, this value is the "smallest width" that your layout supports, regardless of the screen's current orientation).
>
> Some values you might use here for common screen sizes:
>
> 320, for devices with screen configurations such as:
>   240x320 ldpi (QVGA handset),
>   320x480 mdpi (handset),
>   480x800 hdpi (high-density handset)
>
> 480, for screens such as 480x800 mdpi (tablet/handset).
>
> 600, for screens such as 600x1024 mdpi (7" tablet).
>
> 720, for screens such as 720x1280 mdpi (10" tablet).

Answer (score 0):

Even though I don't know why you would want to, but if you did want to make this app to fit only one screen size, you can use the AVD manager. Go to Tools --> Android --> AVD Manager. Then create a new virtual device with the dimensions you want.

You don't have to use this virtual device, but if you create a new one with the dimensions you want, it will appear under the drop down you have shown in your first picture at the very bottom of the spinner.

Comment: Actually i'm having the same issue, i'm clicking on my new created device and it instead of passing to layout-main (norma) open the layout-main (large) and set the size to it...

Comment: Could you try to elaborate more? I am fairly certain you can't just set the size to 5.1" and then make it not large. Large is just associated with any size that is greater than or equal to 5".

Comment: not exactly, look at the first screen, the sizes without "x" will be created in the layout i've oppened while there is other sizes that reffer to >large , like a 5.1" create a large layout while i can make in a normal a 6.0"